# Update list when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Still learning `React` so please be understanding.

In a component I have declared a list of elements. From a parent component when new element is added I pass that element via prop. The problem is that I'd like to update a list only when new element pops in. I have code like that:

```
export default function Expenses(props) {
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(INITIAL_EXPENSES);
const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState('2020');

const filterExpenses = (date) => {
    setFilteredYear(date);
}

if (props.newExpense.hasOwnProperty('expenseTitle')) {
    setExpenses((prev) => {
        const newExpenses = [...prev]
        newExpenses.push(props.newExpense);
        props.newExpense = null;
        return newExpenses;
    })
}
const filteredExpenses = expenses.filter(exp => exp.expenseDate.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear);

return (
    <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilter year={filteredYear} onExpensesFilter={filterExpenses}/>
        <ExpenseChart expenses={filteredExpenses}/>
        <ExpensesList items={filteredExpenses}/>
    </Card>
)
```

}

I suppose that `if`

```
if (props.newExpense.hasOwnProperty('expenseTitle')) {
```

is not well done because somehow `props.newExpense` should be cleared after added to newExpenses list. But I don't know how to do it?

The second trouble which I have is an error `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` which in that form of code is completly fine cause after adding new element to list inside props.newExpense there is still that element so that if again and again is true.

**Please do not change the way how I declared `Expenses` class/function. That's not the point of this issue.**

Comment: Because I saw lots of different solution that doesn’t solve my problem. Please go ahead with the easiest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with your code is basically you're setting the state on every single render, and when you set the state to a new value it triggers another render, which in turn sets the state and...you get the gist.

Enter the `useEffect` hook. `useEffect` allows you to define side effects to changes in particular state or props.

What you want to do here is do something only when the `newExpense` prop changes, so you'd have to do something like that: (Note you need to import `useEffect` from `react`)

```js
useEffect(() => {
if (props.newExpense.hasOwnProperty('expenseTitle')) {
    setExpenses((prev) => {
        const newExpenses = [...prev]
        newExpenses.push(props.newExpense);
        props.newExpense = null;
        return newExpenses;
    })
}, [props.newExpense])
```

The 2nd argument to `useEffect` is a dependency array, meaning if one of the things in the array changes, run the effect function.

Do note that it's seldom a good thing to set the state in `useEffect`, so I do suggest refactoring the mechanism if you can

Comment: You mean refactoring by moving list of elements somewhere else of something different?

Comment: Something like that, maybe not keeping the list in the child component's state and having to change it according to a prop, but rather having the whole list come from the parent, so every time it changes you just pass a new prop. But I don't see the whole picture, I just see a fraction of your app so it's more of a general suggestion

Comment: Actually that code throws error `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` eventhough I use `useEffect`

Comment: Did you just add the part I wrote or did you replace the problematic part (the part that's inside the `useEffect` function)?